# Pushing an item into an array of an array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I've been struggling with this for the last few hours and can't get it to work properly. Read all over Stackoverflow, Google and still can't implement it correctly on my case.

Basically, my document in MongoDB looks like this:

```
{
"_id": "H2RLYBniXZ7Fkszpu",
  "userId": "FmMsoqXxJ8Nd4DRm5",
  "Data": {
    "name": "This is just a test.",
    "summary": "sdadsdas",
    "testId": "EyWcg1vS-",
    "questions": [
      {
        "type": "test",
        "key": "E1eol1DS-",
        "options": []
      }
    ],

}
}
```

My goal is to `$push` and item into the `"Data.questions.options"` array *if* that particular object's `key` in that array is equal to the input I request.

I tried doing this many different ways, including using the `$in` operator, doing things like this:

```
Db.fix.update({_id: "H2RLYBniXZ7Fkszpu"}, {$push: {"Data.questions.$.options": "option"}}); // Pushing the string "option" into the options array
```

I was also looking into the `$cond` operator for MongoDB to see if I can add conditionals, but it's only for aggregation. I'm not sure how to proceed with this. I'm not sure it's even possible doing this with such a nested array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close. The key part with the [$ positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) is that **the array field must appear as part of the query document**.

Try this:

```
db.Fix.update({_id: "H2RLYBniXZ7Fkszpu", "Data.questions.key":"E1eol1DS-"}, {$push: {"Data.questions.$.options": "option"}});
```